# If a GameObject will be activated and deactivated, should it be static?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Say you have some GameObjects which are using Render Mode: Screen Space - Camera. These will be hidden and shown via activation and deactivation. Are they to be considered Static, or no?

Comment: "static" in which context? -> [Static GameObjects](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StaticObjects.html) matter mainly for occlusion, lighting, rendering in general, for things like [nav-mesh baking](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/nav-BuildingNavMesh.html) ... and in [Physics](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html)

Answer (score 1):

In order to activate or deactivate a GameObject it doesn't matter if it's static or not. Unlike a dynamic GameObject a static one has disabled movement
at runtime but it doesn't lock its active state. At least that is my case.